# how to pass an array to a perl cgi script with a HTML form?

Tags: perl, cgi

In a HTML form, if we give names to input boxes with `[]`, like this

```
<input name="foo[]" type="text" />
<input name="foo[]" type="text" />
```

In PHP, we can obtain values of these input boxes in an array, with `$_POST['foo']`.

How to do the similar in Perl? I use CGI.pm

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just assign the result of `param` to an array.

```
my @values = param('foo[]');         # If you use the functional-style
my @values = $query->param('foo[]'); # If you use the OO-style of CGI.pm
```

There's no requirement that the name end with `[]`.

Comment: Be careful.  You should remember to first check for the proper REQUEST_METHOD (GET/POST).  CGI::param() is used to retrieve either `GET` or `POST` request parameters from the header.

Comment: @vol7ron, why would you need to check the request method?  Ordinarily, it doesn't matter which method was used.

Comment: Maybe he means in PHP. In PHP it might be in $_POST but it might also be in $_GET, or of course, both.

Comment: @AmbroseChapel: no, I meant Perl; it's because of the different PHP  handlers that I wanted to make the distinction.

Comment: @cjm: because verifying the request method is an added layer of security, albeit a small one.  It ensures that someone is not tinkering with, or attempting to hack, your code.  Also, the resulting action of your script may depend on the request method used.

Comment: @vol7ron, anybody who would be stopped (or even noticeably slowed) by that "security measure" would never manage to hack your code anyway.  Unless you need to vary the behavior of the script based on the request method, checking it is pointless.  It's just extra complexity in your code.

Comment: @cjm: think what you will.  any hack attempt is well worth identifying earlier, rather than later.  many threats today come from kids that don't know better that soon come across some software that does it for them.  i'm not trying to convince you of anything, i merely pointed out the difference of Perl vs PHP... there are many other reasons other than security to consider.

Comment: Any received data should be fully checked by the server if any security is to be achieved. Checking the request type by itself doesn't add any substantial security, although it can provide some useful information if an attack is attempted and one needs to investigate its source further. Just remember: request type check doesn't replace the need to *always* check and verify any input.